# Memory leak in char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

To be specific, my program uses pointers to char. The program itself runs smooth, but every loop i leak about 8kb of data. As i found out, my mistake lies in my style of using these char pointers. It goes like this:

```
Draw(char *what1, char* onWhat1);  //this is declaration
DrawAgain(char *what2, char* onWhat2); //declaration too

// both take two directories to two images, so i call it like this:

Draw("C:\a.bmp", "C:\b.bmp"){

//so what is pointer to a.bmp onWhat is pointer to b.bmp so i use them like this:

DrawAgain(what1, onWhat1);
}
```

There are no other leaks in program (i removed almost everything to find this out). So my question is: "How do i free this *char memory? And can i free it if i did not allocate it, just typed in."

Comment: There's no leak, nothing to free in this code. If you have a leak, it's not in this code.

Comment: Can you add the declarations of `what1` and `onWhat1` ?

Comment: the leak is not in the posted code please post your complete code

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete and concise.

Comment: Note that you only need to `free` what you `[cm]alloc`, and `delete` what you `new` (and in C++, you should be using the latter for C++ types). If something isn't dynamically allocated with `new` or `[cm]alloc`, then you don't need to explicitly deallocate it, and the memory leak lies elsewhere. Rather than guessing, use a [tool to discover the leak](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6556), such as valgrind (Linux) or Instruments (OS X). SO has [numerous questions about memory leak tools](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tool+memory+leak).

Answer (score 4):

[String literals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/lex.html#lex.string) should not be freed, as they aren't dynamically allocated. The leak doesn't lie in the sample code. From C++03, § 5.13.4-1 String literals:

> An ordinary string literal has type “array of *n* `const char`” and *static* storage duration (3.7) [...] A wide string literal has type “array of *n* `const wchar_t`” and has static storage duration

Answer (score 1):

There is no leak. If you don't allocate memory using `new`, it's not your responsibility to `delete` it unless explicitly stated otherwise. In general, whoever allocates memory is responsible for freeing it. That said, many popular libraries still have leaks in them. If `char*` would be an array or similar which was dynamically allocated on the heap, you need to delete it from where it was allocated (not in these functions).

Regards,
Dennis M.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more problem in the code. I created an OpenCV point and then returned value to it from function, it looks like this:

```
CvPoint Value;

bool Calculations( CvPoint &worker); //declaration
//So i give this function Value and take it out like this:
Calculations(Value){
worker = someValue;
}
```

The value goes out, but i do not call any free() or any deallocator;

Comment: please post your complete code so we have a chance to find the problem

Comment: SO uses a Q&A format, rather than a forum format. Only posts that answer the question should be posted as answers. This information should go in the question. Edit it now and add the info above, then delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your complete code so we can find the problem.

Also you might want to check:

```
Draw("C:\a.bmp", "C:\b.bmp")
```

The '\' escapes the 'a' respective 'b'.